# Understanding consequences of using bad react keys

Tags: reactjs

Recently, I made a trivial mistake using array values instead of indexes for keys like below:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function NamesView(props: {names: string[], setNames(l: string[]) : void}) {
    const {names, setNames} = props;
    function setName(index: number, name: string) {
        setNames(names.map((n, i) => i===index ? name : names[i]));
    }
    return <div>
        {/***** THE key IS WRONG!!! */ }
        {names.map((n, i) => <input key={n} value={n} onChange={e => setName(i, e.target.value)}/>)}
    </div>;
}

function MainView() {
    const [names, setNames] = useState(() => ['one', 'two']);
    return <NamesView names={names} setNames={setNames}/>
}

ReactDOM.render(<MainView/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here, using `key={i}` would be right. What I don't understand is the behavior of the wrong code: Each input can be edited just once. You can add or delete a character or paste something and it works, but all subsequent changes get ignored - until you e.g., change focus.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: So n would be disntinct string in each iteration right?

Comment: @UtsavPatel Right, for the edited input.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed that and posted an answer below.
Hope it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys are used for lists to help React identify which items have changed, been added or been removed. In your case you're using the name as the key, so whenever you update the value of your input field, the key is updated as well. React detects this as an element being removed, and a new element being added.

So instead of just updating the value, React actually removes the input field, and add an input field again, which is why the input loses focus after updating one of the inputs.

Comment: Damn.... I didn't notice the lost focus and thought it was somehow related to the data.

Answer (score 2):

When you are mapping through `names` which is an array of input values. 
You are rendering the inputs in the following way.

```
return (
  <div>
    {/***** THE key IS WRONG!!! */}
    {names.map((n, i) => (
      <input key={n} value={n} onChange={(e) => setName(i, e.target.value)} />
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

As soon as you change the input, `setNames` is triggered through your `setName` via `onChange`.

This means `react` will now check for new items generated.

Since `key={n}` would change the input itself i.e a new input element is generated and updated now in the dom, that is why you lose focus each time when you change it.

This is not the case, when you are using `index` as the key. 
Because then the keys of input remain same and only the value changes.

However, there are some caveats using index as keys too.

You can read more about them here:

1. https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html
2. https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and links. Here, using indexes is right as they're the "natural" keys (in the database sense). I completely missed that the focus was lost...